# MPDF problems with floated div widths

Tags: html, width, mpdf

I have a problem that I am struggling to resolve with MPDF6

I have a web application created using codeigniter, which displays results of a questionnaire survey.

I have generated simple stacked bar charts in html and used jquery to animate the bars to their final sizes.  Works ok, and no problems.

I want to be able to replicate the results in MPDF, so using the same theory of divs and sizing them accordingly, but this time I am setting the widths as inline style using php, and in most cases I have this working fine, however, if the value = 1, then for some reason mpdf goes funky, see example image below;

[Example of MPDF issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngRzN.png)

Here is an example of my php markup for the mpdf report

```
<div class='survey'>
            <?php $nw = 390; $w = 400; $tot=0; $totpos=0; $score=0; $cat=0; foreach ($categories as $c) : ?>
            <p class='left question'><?php echo $c->category_name; ?></p>
            <p class='left perc'><?php echo number_format($summaryAnswers[$cat][6],1); ?>%</p>
            <p class='left perc'><?php echo number_format($summaryAnswers[$cat][7],2); ?></p>
            <div  style='width: <?php echo $w; ?>px;'  class='left chart'>
                <?php if ($summaryAnswers[$cat][0] > 0) : ?>
                    <div class='left barchart sagree' style='width: <?php $width = $nw * $summaryAnswers[$cat][0]/$summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; echo $width; ?>px;' tot='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; ?>' val='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][0]; ?>' ><span class='label'><?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][0]; ?></span></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($summaryAnswers[$cat][1] > 0) : ?>
                    <div class='left barchart agree' style='width: <?php $width = $nw * $summaryAnswers[$cat][1]/$summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; echo $width; ?>px;' tot='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; ?>' val='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][1]; ?>' ><span class='label'><?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][1]; ?></span></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($summaryAnswers[$cat][2] > 0) : ?>
                    <div class='left barchart neither' style='width: <?php $width = $nw * $summaryAnswers[$cat][2]/$summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; echo $width; ?>px;' tot='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; ?>' val='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][2]; ?>'  ><span class='label'><?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][2]; ?></span></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($summaryAnswers[$cat][3] > 0) : ?>
                    <div class='left barchart disagree' style='width: <?php $width = $nw * $summaryAnswers[$cat][3]/$summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; echo $width; ?>px;' tot='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; ?>' val='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][3]; ?>'  ><span class='label'><?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][3]; ?></span></div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($summaryAnswers[$cat][4] > 0) : ?>
                    <div class='left barchart sdisagree' style='width: <?php $width = $nw * $summaryAnswers[$cat][4]/$summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; echo $width; ?>px;' tot='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][5]; ?>' val='<?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][4]; ?>'  ><span class='label'><?php echo $summaryAnswers[$cat][4]; ?></span></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

I have tried both px width and %width both options give me the same result...

here is the html that is generated by the script, you can see the values of each width look correct

```
<div class='survey'>
                            <p class='left question'>Organisation and Culture</p>
            <p class='left perc'>66.7%</p>
            <p class='left perc'>2.92</p>
            <div  style='width: 400px;'  class='left chart'>
                                        <div class='left barchart sagree' style='width: 97.5px;' tot='24' val='6' ><span class='label'>6</span></div>

                                        <div class='left barchart agree' style='width: 162.5px;' tot='24' val='10' ><span class='label'>10</span></div>

                                        <div class='left barchart neither' style='width: 32.5px;' tot='24' val='2'  ><span class='label'>2</span></div>

                                        <div class='left barchart disagree' style='width: 81.25px;' tot='24' val='5'  ><span class='label'>5</span></div>

                                        <div class='left barchart sdisagree' style='width: 16.25px;' tot='24' val='1'  ><span class='label'>1</span></div>
                                </div>


            <br class='clear' />
```

the css..

```
.survey { font-size: 10pt; }
.survey .question   { width: 47%; padding: 5px 0;  }
.survey .perc       { width: 5%; margin: 0; padding: 5px 0; }   
.survey .no         { width: 2%; margin: 0; padding: 5px 0; }   
.survey .chart      { width: 40%;  }    
.survey .barchart   { padding: 5px 0; }
.barchart .label    { margin: 0 0 0 5px; }
div.sagree { background: #2DCC00; }
div.agree { background: #F2E930; }
div.neither { background: #888; }
div.disagree{ background: #FFA519; }
div.sdisagree { background: #FF1919;  }
.right { float: right; }
.left { float: left; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

anyone got any ideas why this is happening?

cheers

Comment: Could you please add your css for these classes? Would be way easier to check this case.

Comment: Probably you can gather some helpful informations here [Floating blocks](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html)

Comment: thanks, but I have seen the article before, was helpful as i managed to get the divs floating, but the width is the issue for me...

Comment: Hi Andie, did you find a solution for this issue? I'm also getting the same issue, still can't find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution which worked for me, through a lot of trial and error...

I created a container div and set the width of the div in % using inline css, then each floated div within the container, was set a width as a % too a bit like this:

```
<div style='width: 80%'>
    <div style='float: left; width: 20%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 30%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 40%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 10%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 5%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 15%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 40%'>Content</div>
    <div style='float: left; width: 40%'>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As this was selected as the answer, it appears that the problem was the `"float:right"` not being applied by mPDF.

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled on the same problem (putting smaller widths to `div` and mPDF turning them into 100%).

My solution was to convert the `div` into a table, and give widths (percentages) to each `td`. Works as expected.

NOTE: obviously if the content is too wide, it may force the `td` to expand, but even so, we can have mPDF to fit/resize the contents!

Example:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:20%">20</td>
    <td style="width:40%">40</td>
    <td style="width:10%">10</td>
    <td style="width:5%">5</td>
    <td style="width:25%">25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```